# Jest - how to mock a class in jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I've been trying to mock a test in jest through the methods that they have on their documentation. By mocking the whole class but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

```
jest.mock('../../../../../src/SubscriptionOrder');
    SubscriptionOrder.prototype.createChargebeeSubscription = jest.fn(() => 'response');

const test = new SubscriptionOrder(
  'subscription',
  [{}],
  'errorMethods',
  'customerMethods',
);
test.createChargebeeSubscription();
```

I'd expect this to mock the createChargebeeSubscription method and return the string response but it seems to be returning undeifined

Then this is the piece of code I'm trying to run a test for as well.

```
      const subscriptionOrder = new SubscriptionOrder(
    'subscription',
    subscriptionRequest,
    errorMethods,
    customerMethods,
  );
  const response = await subscriptionOrder.createChargebeeSubscription(token);
  this.setState({ successfulSubmit: response });
```

I want to update the state to the string response but getting undefined instead. so it appears I'm kinda mocking something but just not properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spyOn` as follows to do the mocking for you. I also recommend that you set up and tear down this spy once you are finished.

So here's a sample piece of code which will do what you want:

```
describe('createChargebeeSubscription() method behaviour', () => {
  let createChargebeeSubscriptionSpy;
  let testResponse;

  beforeAll(() => {
   // Lets create an instance of your class first
   const subscriptionOrder = new SubscriptionOrder(
     'subscription',
     subscriptionRequest,
     errorMethods,
     customerMethods
   );

   // Now use a spy to mock the return value from your function
   createChargebeeSubscriptionSpy = jest.spyOn(subscriptionOrder, 'createChargebeeSubscription').mockImplementation(() => {
     return 'response';
   });

   // Finally invoke the method being tested
   testResponse = subscriptionOrder.createChargebeeSubscription();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    // Restore the functionality (ie. disable the spy) of your method
    createChargebeeSubscriptionSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('verifies that the expected response was returned', () => {
    expect(testResponse).toBe('response');
  });
});
```